# Vscode-R; permission denied to access request.log file

Tags: r, windows, visual-studio-code

I am learning R and followed the instructions to program [R using Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/r). I then tried to run the following line of code to learn how to read data.

```
dat <- read.table("d.data")
View(dat)
```

where d.data is a data file. I received the following error:

```
cannot open file '...\.vscode-R/request.log': Permission denied.
```

I tried using the "Give Access To" command from right-clicking the file in File Explorer, however, I don't think it did anything. How do I grant the program/terminal permission to open the file? It may be significant to note that running the same commands using the radian console works without any issues (I get the data outputted in a separate window).

Comment: When accessing the Security properties of the folder and file in File Explorer, all users can already read/modify the file.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for this issue by adjusting these settings in VSCode:

```
"r.alwaysUseActiveTerminal": true,
"r.bracketedPaste": true,
```

Then, by calling radian in an opened cmd terminal, I was able to load everything without any issues